# ES6 import of JSON returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, es6-modules

When I want to import JSON into my Node application following es6 like this:

```
import * as config from "./server-config.json" assert {type: 'json'}
```

When I try to use the imported values like this

```
console.log(config["url"])
```

It will just return the value `undefined`. I am having this problem using Node 19, the path is correct, the json is correct and even if I use `--experimental-json-modules` it will return an `undefined`.

Comment: "Experimental" means "might not work". Why is it so critical that you *import* the file? Just use fs.readFileSync and JSON.parse the contents.

Comment: What does `console.log(config)` show?

Comment: Related: [Import '.json' extension in ES6 Node.js throws an error](/a/60206393/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON module is equivalent to an ES6 module with default export.

The line

```
import * as config from "./server-config.json" assert {type: 'json'}
```

imports the JSON module into `config.default`. You can either log it with

```
console.log(config.default["url"])
```

or import the default export with

```
import config from "./server-config.json" assert {type: 'json'}
```

and log with

```
console.log(config["url"])
```

More info about JSON import: https://v8.dev/features/import-assertions

Answer (score -2):

If there were several functions/objects/arrays/consts were exported in one file and you wanted to import them all as a single object in that case `import * as everything from "./moduleLocation"` would be correct.

In your case, there is a single JSON object in the `server-config.json` file located in the project root. Therefore, it would be appropriate to import that JSON object, if it was exported, as a single object.

```
import config from "./server-config.json";
```

In order to be able to read that JSON object data you will need to parse it to the object:

```
const serverConfigs = JSON.parse(config);
```

Now you can read/access everything from `serverConfigs`;

Comment: You have to parse strings. `import` won't import `config` as a string.

Comment: Again: `config` won't be a string. You can't parse it. You can only parse strings.

Comment: `config["url"]` being `undefined` is pretty clear.

Comment: https://v8.dev/features/import-assertions The import imports an object, not a JSON string.

Comment: @jkalandarov I think you should test this code and see that it wont work.. you can't use ESM syntax to import a json file without asserting the type as json